# Cannot resolve inflater and container

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, android-studio

Why in my activity "inflater and container" are not resolved? How should i write them?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

private ProgressBar progress;
private WebView myWebView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myUIUpdate();
    return null;
}

private void myUIUpdate() {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);


    String url = "http://gsmarena.com";
    myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewGames);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progress = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    progress.setMax(100);


    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
            View.loadUrl(url);
            GamesFragment.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            return true;
        }

    });


    myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener()

    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}


private class myWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        GamesFragment.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed()) {
        myUIUpdate();
    }
}

public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);
}


}
```

I am trying to attach myUIUdate because to hide my fragment when its not visible on screen using this:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed()) {
        myUIUpdate();
    }
    }
```

PS: if anyone has better idea to hide fragment i like to hear it.

Comment: Can you point out the exact line where the errors are shown? Btw, I see that inflator and container are not instance variables. Where are you initializing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacause in  `myUIUpdate()`  method it did not find `inflater` and `container`.Therfore in `onCreateView` write  myUIUpdate(); as

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myUIUpdate(inflater,container);
}
```

and change (Change `return type` also)  as

```
private void myUIUpdate() {
```

to

```
private View myUIUpdate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
```

**Edit**
Write `myUIUpdate` in [onViewCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)) method and remove from [onCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) as

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    myUIUpdate(view);
}
```

and rewrite `myUIUpdate` method as

```
private void myUIUpdate(View view) {
    String url = "http://gsmarena.com";
    myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webViewGames);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    progress.setMax(100);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
            View.loadUrl(url);
            GamesFragment.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            return true;
        }

    });

    myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener() {@Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: After applying it. myUIUpdate(); in 
Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
        if (visible && isResumed()) {
            myUIUpdate();
        }
    }
gives me an error " myUIUpdate ( layoutinflater, ViewGroup) in GamesFragment cannot be applied to ()

Comment: after adding your code, application crashes take a look at log
E/AndroidRuntime(30911):  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Once again after adding you edited code myUpdate() view in gamesfragment cannot be applied error comes in 
 boolean isResumed = false;
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser); {
                if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {

            myUIUpdate();
            isResumed = true;
        }

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
   private void myUIUpdate()
```

to

```
   private void myUIUpdate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container)
```

and pass inflater and container to it:

```
   myUIUpdate(inflater, container);
```

Answer (score 0):

LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState these are local to the block in which you used

Answer (score 0):

No need to create custom method to intialize all view from layout in fragment, Try to override onViewCreated and move all your myUIUpdate() code to onViewCreated.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webViewGames);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        progress.setMax(100);


        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
                View.loadUrl(url);
                GamesFragment.this.progress.setProgress(0);
                return true;
            }

        });


        myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener()

        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                                webView.goBack();
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `inflater` and `container` in

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myUIUpdate();
    return null;
}
```

and they're local in there. You have to either pass them as parameters to `myUIUpdate` or declare fields inside your `Activity` and assign them inside `onCreateView` (which is an ugly solution).